# Optimising UIViewTable with big number of cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, optimization

I have a table that has up to 1600 cells in it each containing one line of text and one picture. As you would probably expect, it is very laggy when scrolling. How to make non-visible cells (that are 2 screens away from visible, for instance) unload themselves? And are there any other ways to reduce lag?

Code for updating cells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell
    var item = receivedData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
    var imgURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: item["url"] as NSString)
    var imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)
    cell.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
    cell.text = item["name"] as NSString
    return cell
}
```

Comment: UITableViews use lazy loading by default, so anything off screen is unloaded automatically.  the lag is due to either too many `[table reloadData]` calls or because of excessive cell load time.

Comment: @Putz1103 Could the problem be in that cells are not reusable?

Comment: They should get released in any case.  But recreating cells is the slowdown that Apple tried to resolve with the reusable cell thing.  If your cells are all the same then re-using them would be a good idea.

Comment: @Putz1103 well, I made this cell style reusable. Still awfully laggy.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the looks of it there is *cellIdentifier* being used in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method where as there is no static declaration for *cellIdentifier*.
2. Register the cell identifier in viewDidLoad.

   - (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

Check whether the cell are being reused or not.

Comment: I set cell identifier in storyboard by adding a prototype cell and adding an identifier `MyPrototypeCell` to it. And in ViewController declaration there is `var cellIdentifier:NSString = "MyPrototypeCell"`

Comment: In the code you are creating a UITableViewCell using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. There no check for if the _cell_ is nil. The alloc init for UITableViewCell is not there in exception case. 2.The images you are loading from NSURL which might take time to update in the cell as it has to load from server you can achieve this in background using `dispatch_queue`.

Comment: Well, thank you for noticing about check, but I am on early development stage though, so I have bigger issues to worry about as of now. So, the problem might be in constant reloading? What could be an easy and good way to cache these images?